# How to make IE not to cache my page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC for angular JS for front end, when I login to my application with the first user credentials I am able to view the correct details.

When I login with the next user again I am seeing the details of the first user.
This happens only in IE. I need to clear the cookies manually to see the right details before i login with different usernames.

I browsed and added some code in HTML but it didnt work out.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'/>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='-1'/>
```

But, there is no change when I used the above code also.

Comment: You are probably fetching the details with AJAX, just add a random parameter with a random value, and IE should stop caching it.

Comment: Yes, I am using AJAX. What is the random paramter?

Answer (score 2):

You can force Internet Explorer not to cache your page using the following headers:

```
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
```

See [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)

Comment: Should we need to add in servlet code as mentioned in the example

Comment: Do you really need expires too?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/setup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String setupGroupDetails(@RequestParam String name, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);` }                                                                  I used the above code in controller method but still the  page is getting cached @sami

Comment: I used a random string to my url for the pages those are getting cached and I solved the issued